# Cómo puedo crear una condición que dependa de la ejecución de una función?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

La función antes mencionada se ejecuta al presionar un botón, y mi idea es que se realice cierta acción cuando se le da click a ese botón. Estoy utilizando Ecmascript, JavaScript y HTML.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la bienvenida! El problema es que no sé cómo hacer el código, cómo armar la condición, por eso no he subido nada de código, porque no tengo.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es bastante genérica, por lo que la respuesta también lo es. Me imagino que tendrás un botón en HTML. Ese botón lo puedes declarar así:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Ahora puedes definir una función en javascript como esta.

```
    function myFunction() {
      //Codigo
    }
```

Esa función sera llamada cuando hagas clic en el botón. Para más info puedes ver https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp